# C# Regex extract HTML text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a HTML string that I just want the text from:

```
string html = "<span class="MyText" id="1">     SomeText blah blah</span>";
```

So I use the following expression:

```
public static string StripHTMLTags(string source)
{
    return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

But sometimes the HTML string contains several lines of HTML:

```
string html = "<span class="MyText" id="1">SomeText blah blah</span<br><span class="MyText" id="2">SomeText blah blah 1</span><br><span class="MyText" id="2">SomeText blah blah2</span>";
```

So now I want to extract out the text that is between the `<span>` tags and store them in a list or array or lines.

**NOTE:**
I am parsing custom HTML that will only have **two tags** the break and span tags.

How can I do this using Regex?

Comment: HTML is not regular enough to be parsed with regular expressions ;)

Comment: I am parsing custom HTML that will only have two tags <br> and <span class="something" id="someid">

Comment: My application is a C# windows application that receives HTML text from a server.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML with Regex is cumbersome and errorprone. Have a look at the rather famous StackOverflow post [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

I suggest to use a library for that. One that is widely used is the Html Agility Pack at http://html-agility-pack.net available via Nuget.

EDIT:

In order to get the inner text of HTML you can use something like this:

```
var pageDoc = new HtmlDocument();
pageDoc.LoadHtml(pageContent);
var pageText = pageDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Comment: I am parsing custom HTML that will only have two tags <br> and <span class="something" id="someid">

Comment: @HarryBoy - this may change over time. I have a sample added to the post. I think the code is easier to understand than a RegEx-Expression that can get rather complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can solve this with a different REGEX statement (just don't know much about regular expressions), but what you could do is split the string every time a "><" occurs and then extract the text of each of those substrings.

Also http://regexr.com/ might help you trying different statements.

Edit: Is there always a '< br>' after a '< /span>' ?

Comment: No there is not always a '<br>', only when there are several lines received is there a '<br>'

Answer (score 0):

Beware if running in non-private application. As I said:

> HTML is not regular enough to be parsed with regular expressions

However, this simple HTML snippets can be parsed with following one:

```
string txt =
    @"""<span class=""MyText"" id=""1"">SomeText blah blah</span<br><span class=""MyText"" id=""2"">SomeText blah blah 1</span><br><span class=""MyText"" id=""2"">SomeText blah blah2</span>""";

var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, "(?<=>)([^<]+)(?=<)");
foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

It yields:

```
SomeText blah blah
SomeText blah blah 1
SomeText blah blah2
```